# Python List in List ("Stuck")

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def lists(): #Where list is stored
    List = ["Movie_Name",[""],"Movie_Stars",[""],"Movie_Budget",[""]] 

    print ("Your Movies")

    amount_in_list = int(input("How many Movies? "))
    x = 1
    while x <= amount_in_list:
        film = input ("Name of film ... ")
        stars = input ("Main stars ...")
        Budget = input ("Budget ...")
        List.append["Movie_Name"](film)
        List.append["Movie_Stars"](stars)
        List.append["Movie_Budget"](Budget)

lists()
```

How do i add the film you enter to the list under the subsetting Movie_Name etc?

Comment: Looks like you should use a `dictionary` and not a `list`.

Comment: it would be much easier to create a class with the name Movie. then you can store your movie instances in a list...

Comment: How do i do that @kasperTaeymans

Comment: `List[1].append(film)` would solve your current problem. However as others stated there are better ways to achieve your goal, like dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better answer than one which answers your question directly would be: You don't. You definitely need a dictionary for this situation (unless your program develops to a point where you'd prefer creating a custom object)

As a simple demonstration:

```
def getMovies():

    movieinfo = {"Movie_Name": [], "Movie_Stars": [], "Movie_Budget": []}
    print ("Your Movies")
    amount_in_list = int(input("How many Movies? "))

    x = 1
    while x <= amount_in_list:
        film = input ("Name of film ... ")
        stars = input ("Main stars ...")
        budget = input ("Budget ...")
        movieinfo["Movie_Name"].append(film)
        movieinfo["Movie_Stars"].append(stars)
        movieinfo["Movie_Budget"].append(budget)
        x+=1

    return movieInfo
```

Notice that with a `dict` you simply use the `key` string to get the corresponding list (initialized at the start of the function) and append the data as desired.

**Edited to provide further information for OP's updated request.**

If you want to find a movie's info based on just the movie's name given by the user, you could try something like this:

```
film = 'The Matrix' # Assuming this is the user's input.

Try:
    # The index method will throw an exception if
    # the movie cannot be found. If that happens,
    # the 'except' clause will execute and print
    # the relevant statement.
    mIdx = movieinfo['Movie_Name'].index(film)

    print '{0} stars {1} and had a reported budget of {2}'.format(
        film, movieInfo['Movie_Stars'][mIdx], movieInfo['Movie_Budget'][mIdx])

except ValueError:
   print '{0} is not in the movie archives. Try another?'.format(film)
```

**Output**:

```
'The Matrix stars Keanu Reeves and had a reported budget of $80 million'
```

**Or**:

```
'The Matrix is not in the movie archives. Try another?'
```

Comment: May i ask how can you get it so the user can search a name of the movie and get all its details i tried            print ("Type movie name")
        searchData = input ("...")
        if searchData in movieinfo ({"Movie_Name"}):
            print ("In list")
        else:
            print ("Not in list")
            Menu(movieinfo)

Comment: @user3813197 Updated my answer. See if the general idea works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the movie information in an object. This way your code will be easier to extend, make changes and reuse. you could easily add methods to your movie class to do custom stuff or add more properties without having to change your code to much.

```
   class Movie:
        def __init__(self, name='', actors=[], rating=0 budget=0):
            self.name=name
            self.actors=actors
            self.budget=budget
            self.rating=rating

        def setName(self, newname):
            self.name=newname

        def setActors(self, newstars):
            self.actors=newstars

        def setBudget(self, newbudget):
            self.budget=newbudget

        def setRating(self, newrating):
            self.rating=newrating

    # example
    mymovies=[]

    movie1= Movie('Interstellar',['actor1','actor2','actor3'], 5, 100000)


    movie2=Movie()
    movie2.setName('other movie')
    movie2.setActors(['actor1','actor2','actor3'])
    movie2.setBudget(10000)

    mymovies.append(movie1)
    mymovies.append(movie2)
    # or append to your list in a loop
```

Comment: I like it but, i need to use list inside a list #School but thats a good way thanks for showing me this way of coding i will use this in my own codes as in the class and def the changeBudget(self,) never knew you could do that :)

Comment: adapted the answer... I was confused with "stars"

Comment: Ooo i should of put actors sorru

Comment: Cheers, very kind of you